# I want to mint an NFT using a JSON file using plu-ts, but I dont know how and where to start

Tags: cardano-cli, cardano-node, smart-contract, nft, plu-ts

I want to mint an NFT using a JSON file using `plu-ts`, but I don't know how and where to start.

*Do I need to create a Node?* **OR** *Do I need to write it in Haskel?* I have read and performed everything from the official documentation of the `plu-ts` but it has been confusing for me. If anyone can help me out here I'll be very thankful. Even a video would help.

Answer (score 0):

Why plutus? It sounds like a native script is perfect for your use case. https://developers.cardano.org/docs/native-tokens/minting/